# EF include not getting the data correctly

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have a `Product` dataset and reviews. The product entity has an `ICollection` of reviews.

When someone is reviewing a product, I want to do a check if he already reviewed this product before, for somehow I am getting an error if the reviews were not taken.

This is my `Product` entity:

```
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Condition { get; set; }
    public DateTime publishDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductPurchaser> Purchasers { get; set; } = new List<ProductPurchaser>();
    public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductPhoto> Photos { get; set; }

    public double ReviewsAverage { get; set; }
```

And here I am trying to take the product+reviews and make the check :

```
var product = await _context.Products
                            .Include(r => r.Reviews)
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == request.ProductId);

if (product == null) 
{
    return null;
}

var user = await _context.Users
                         .Include(p => p.Photos)
                         .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == _userAccessor.GetUsername());

var wasReviewed = product.Reviews
                         .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Author.UserName == user.UserName)
                         .Author.UserName;

if(wasReviewed == user.UserName)
{
    return null;
}
```

This is the builder entity of the review:

```
  builder.Entity<Review>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Product)
        .WithMany(r => r.Reviews)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Comment: if(wasReviewed == user.UserName) -  it will be always true

Comment: off topic, but if  you expecting a record you shouldn't  query for [Single/First]OrDefault

Comment: Hey,why bot? Shouldnt it return the one product that match the id?

Comment: First, your query should be like this to avoid null reference exception `var wasReviewed = product.Reviews?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Author.UserName == user.UserName)?.Author?.UserName;` and `if(wasReviewed == null) return null;` and your question has nothing todo with `Include`.

Comment: Assuming it's a null-reference exception which is basically caused by having so many queries. Doing it in one query gets rid of all possible errors (assuming that the model itself is OK).

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated way to check if a product already has any reviews by the current user. It can be reduced to one query:

```cs
var productId = request.ProductId;
var currentUserName = _userAccessor.GetUsername();

bool isReviewed = _context.Products
    .Any(p => p.Id == productId
           && p.Reviews.Any(r => r.Author.UserName == currentUserName));
```

So this says: check if there's a product with this specific id, that has any reviews of which the author's name equals the current user's name.

Not only is it simpler, it's also much cheaper: it's only one query that only returns one bit value from the database.